# Скучаю: по вам, по вас или за вас?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Как будет правильно: *я скучаю **по вам**, я скучаю **по вас** или  я скучаю **за вас***?
Почему-то последнее выражение слышу чаще всего.

Comment: Ещё есть южное "за вами"? Вы уверены, что "за вас" тоже есть?

Answer (score 12):

Возможны оба варианта, но предпочтительным пока следует считать вариант скучаю по вас.

Скучаю (а также грущу, тоскую и т. п.) по вас – старая норма; по вам – новая. Прежние лингвистические издания рекомендовали как нормативные только скучать по вас, по нас. Сегодня эти варианты конкурируют, что находит отражение и в справочниках. Так, «Русская грамматика» (М., 1980) формы скучать по вам и скучать по вас рассматривает как вариативные.

В справочнике Д. Э. Розенталя «Управление в русском языке» указано, что с существительными и местоимениями 3-го лица правильно: скучать по кому-чему, например: скучать по сыну, скучать по нему. Но с личными местоимениями 1-го и 2-го лица мн. числа правильно: скучать по ком, например: скучали по нас, скучаем по вас.

А вот вариант скучать за кем-либо, о котором тоже довольно часто спрашивают, не является нормативным, выходит за рамки русского литературного языка.

Comment: `предпочтительным пока следует считать вариант скучаю по вас` — но почему? Заменяем местоимение на существительное (*скучаю по (чему?) коню*), и тут же выяснится, что предложный падеж не удастся натянуть даже при всём желании (скучаю по коне́?)

Answer (score 9):

Старая норма - *скучать по вас* (это предложный падеж, а не родительный). Новая - *скучать по вам*. Ещё академическая "Грамматика-80" давала эти варианты как равнозначные. В некоторых справочниках отдается предпочтение старой норме, в некоторых - новой. Интересно, что во многих пособиях по подготовке к ЕГЭ вернулись к старой норме и требуют знания правильного "скучать по вас".

Comment: Спасибо. Падеж, конечно же, предложный. Я б могла и по вопросу догадаться.

Answer (score 5):

В XIX веке нормой было употребление с предлогом по форм предложного падежа местоимений кто, что, он, мы, вы: по ком, по чем, по нас, по вас. А. Х. Востоков в "Русской грамматике" (СПб., 1834) приводит такой пример: По ком стреляли? По неприятелю".
В современном русском языке местоимения кто, что и он выступают обычно в форме дательного падежа: есть по кому равняться, открыли огонь по нему. Формы по ком, по чем, по нем признаются устаревшими. Однако местоимения мы и вы продолжают выступать в описываемых конструкциях в форме предложного падежа. Вот примеры из русской литературы: Из окна по нас стреляли (К. Паустовский); Несколько человек, положив винтовки на колено, прицеливались по нас (Д. Фурманов). В справочнике Л. К. Граудиной, В. А. Ицковича, Л. П. Катлинской "Грамматическая правильность русской речи" утверждается, что "формы по нам, по вам еще нельзя считать литературной нормой, хотя они встречаются в печати". (Итак, правильно: они открыли по нас огонь (предложный падеж) и они открыли по нему огонь (дательный падеж); По кому открыть огонь? (дательный падеж); стрелять по своим).

Скучаю, грущу, тоскую по вас - старая норма; скучаю, грущу, тоскую по вам - новая. Сегодня эти варианты конкурируют, что находит отражение и в справочниках.
Согласно "Толковому словарю русского языка" С. И. Ожегова и Н. Ю. Шведовой (М., 1997)правильно: скучаю по вам (дат. п.), скучаю о вас (предл. пад.). Устарелое и просторечное - скучаю по вас (предл. пад.). Прежние справочники рекомендовали как нормативные только скучать по вас, по нас.

Академическая "Русская грамматика" 1980 года скучать по вам и скучать по вас рассматривает как равноправные варианты. А вот Согласно "Толковому словарю русского языка" С. И. Ожегова и Н. Ю. Шведовой правильно: скучаю по вам, рядом с скучаю по вас стоят пометы «устарелое и просторечное».

Кстати, этот словарь разрешает нам скучать, грустить, тосковать и о вас. Такая форма возможна. А вот что категорически запрещено – так это скучать за вами.

http://gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords/25_294

Comment: "Платонов: Не скучно, а очень скучно, душа моя. За вами скучал страшно... Как кстати для меня теперь мои глаза! Видеть вас, Анна Петровна, после долгого, томительнейшего безлюдья и сквернолюдья - да ведь это непростительная роскошь!" - А.П.Чехов, "Платонов"              Но  век  назад  было  вполне  литературным  и  вполне  русским.  Может  это  словосочетание  лучще  не  запрещённым  считать,  а  устаревшим.

Comment: Запрещённое для литературного языка,у Чехова это речевая характеристика героя, способ передачи чисто народной речи - с просторечиями и диалектизмами.

Comment: С  просторечиями  и  диалектизмами  говорят  персонажи  из  простонародья.

Answer (score 4):

**Скучать** - о ком-чем,  по кому-чему и по ком-чем. 1. о ком-чем. Бедный старик
очень скучает обо мне и пишет мне пресмешные письма... (Мамин-Сибиряк). 2. по  кому-чему (с существительными и личными местоимениями 3-го л.). Скучать по сыну. 
Скучать по детям. Скучать по нему. Скучать по ним. Вы давно не учились, и понятно, что скучаете по книге (Вс. Иванов). **3. по ком-чем (с личными местоимениями 1-го и 2-го л. мн. ч.). Скучали по нас. Скучаем по вас.** (Д. Э. Розенталь. "Управление в русском языке")

Comment: Господа, может быть, пусть всё так и остаётся? Чётко, ясно и, главное, грамотно.

Comment: Это вы у русского языка спросите, останется оно или нет. По мне так  вряд ли. Третий вариант, похоже, отмирает.

Answer (score 4):

> **Скучаю** (а также грущу, тоскую и т. п.) **по вас** – старая норма; **по вам** – новая. Прежние лингвистические издания рекомендовали как нормативные только *скучать по вас, по нас*. Сегодня эти варианты
>   конкурируют, что находит отражение и в справочниках.

См. также [ЗДЕСЬ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC):

> Скучать - о ком-чем, по кому-чему и по ком-чем. 1. о ком-чем. *Бедный
>   старик очень скучает обо мне и пишет мне пресмешные письма...*
>   (Мамин-Сибиряк). 2. по кому-чему (с существительными и личными
>   местоимениями 3-го л.). *Скучать по сыну. Скучать по детям. Скучать по
>   нему. Скучать по ним. Вы давно не учились, и понятно, что скучаете по
>   книге* (Вс. Иванов). 3. по ком-чем (с личными местоимениями 1-го и
>   2-го л. мн. ч.). *Скучали по нас. Скучаем по вас.* (Д. Э. Розенталь.
>   "Управление в русском языке")

---

**[Можно ли говорить «я скучаю за тобой» вместо «я скучаю по тебе»?](https://thequestion.ru/questions/275/mozhno-li-govorit-ya-skuchayu-za-toboi-vmesto-ya-skuchayu-po-tebe)**

Ольга Ткаченко, старший преподаватель кафедры русского языка и стилистики Литературного института им. А. М. Горького

> Грамотному человеку, носителю русского литературного языка, так
>   говорить нельзя. Это неверный вариант русского управления, сложившийся
>   под влиянием украинского и закрепившийся в некоторых диалектах как
>   регулярная ошибка. Если кто-то хочет спародировать украинскую речь, то
>   такая фраза придется к месту.

Answer (score 1):

В Толковом словаре русского языка С. И. Ожегова и Н. Ю. Шведовой 1997 года утверждается, что правильно говорить — *скучаю по вам* (в дательном падеже) и *скучаю о вас* (в предложном падеже).

А *скучаю по вас* (в предложном падеже) – это устарелое и просторечное выражение.

Источник:  [Блог РУССКОЕ СЛОВО](http://wordru.ru/skuchayu-po-vam-po-vas-ili-o-vas/)©

Answer (score 0):

Я не буду спорить, *что там в ЕГЭ* (он уже давно стал притчей во языцех), но вы совершенно верно ставите вопрос. **Скучать** (тосковать, горевать) **по ком** — единственный случай использования в современном языке предложного падежа с предлогом "по" в таком значении.
**По ком звонит колокол** — очевидная стилизация. Все это позволяет определить вариант "скучать по вас" как архаичный и просторечно-разговорный.
Современный нормативный язык тяготеет к **по вам** и **о вас**.

А вот народная форма "скучать за вами" слух совсем не режет.

Comment: А мне режет. Это пришло из южных диалектов и мною восптинимается как ненормативное.

Comment: Так не только вами. Ненормативное, кто спорит. Но не все, что ненормативно, режет слух.

Comment: И мне режет.

Comment: Вынужден признать, что сейчас и мне стало казаться слишком уж просторечным. Возможно тогда я был под впечатлением от чего-то прочитанного... Хотя не могу вспомнить, чего. Или общался с кем-то... Привык к этому "за Вами". У меня такое бывает. То, что слышишь постоянно уже не кажется диким...

Comment: behemothus@ Это не просторечие какое-то, это норма другого языка. В данном случае - украинского, хоть тут и определяли его как вариант русского, но все же формально он полноценный кодифицированный язык.

Comment: @Варяг-91, сразу: я для меня украинский никогда не был "вариантом русского", и никаких разговоров на эту тему я не вел и ни с кем вести не собираюсь. Что касается нормы другого языка, то одно другого не исключает, что просторечно в одном языке, то может быть нормой в другом - и наоборот. Но давайте уточним сразу, вы о какой из двух форм печь ведете? *Скучать по ком* или *Скучать за кем*? Мы тут обе разбирали, *скучать за вами* - эта форма  не из украинского точно, и разговор про "резать слух" был о ней. *А скучать по вас* - ну тут да, украинизм и архаизм, но мы  и не расходились в оценке.

Comment: @behemothus Я не Вас имел в виду, упоминая о "варианте". Года 3-4 назад была у нас такая дискуссия. А относительно нашего вопроса - пример:  "Соскучился по тебе"  переводится на украинский как "Скучив за тобою" ."Я скучаю по Родине" соответственно переводится: "Я скучаю за Батьківщиною". Это не суржик, а вполне себе литературная украинская речь. Так что - ошибаетесь.

Comment: *"Соскучился по тебе" переводится на украинский как "Скучив за тобою"* - здравствуй, гугл? А вот "Океан Ельзи" співає ***Я сумую за тобою***. Еще есть хорошее слово **нудьговати**. Да дело не в этом.))) Я имел в виду, что форма "за тобою" вряд ли вошла в русский из украинского.

Comment: @behemothus"Океан Ельзи" співає "Я сумую за тобою." Здравствуй, гугл, как Вы выразились. Но, владея украинским(таким, каков он был в мои детские годы), я перевожу на русский: "я грущу по тебе". "Еще есть хорошее слово нудьговати". Вообще-то "нудьгувати". Наверное можно перевести и  "скучать". Когда художественный перевод. Но точнее было бы, на мой взгляд, - тосковать, тужить, печалиться. Это уже дело вкуса. Тут точности в нестойком субъекте под названием "украинский язык" не может быть. Он еще строится.

Answer (score -2):

Личные местоимения склоняются:
я - р.п. нет меня, д.п. дам мне, в.п. вижу меня, т.п. любуются мной, п.п. мечтают обо мне;
мы - р.п. нет нас, д.п. дадут нам, в.п. видят нас, т.п. любуются нами, п.п. мечтают о нас;
ты - р.п. нет тебя, д.п. дам тебе, в.п. вижу тебя, т.п. любуюсь тобой, п.п. мечтаю о тебе;
вы - р.п. нет вас, дадим вам, в.п. - вижу вас, т.п. восхищаюсь вами, п.п. забочусь о вас;
он - р.п. нет его, д.п. дам ему, в.п. вижу его, т.п. горжусь им, п.п. вспоминаю о нём;
она - р.п. нет её, д.п. дам ей, в.п. вижу её, т.п. восхищаюсь ей, п.п. думаю о ней;
оно - р.п. нет его, дам ему, вижу его, восхищаюсь им, думаю о нём.
Предложный падеж. О ком, о чём (говорю, пишу, думаю, вспоминаю, скучаю)?- О ВАС.
«Мы скучали (о ком?) - О ВАС».

Точно так же звучит эта фраза и с добавлением буквы «п» к предлогу «о», ПАДЕЖ  ОТ ЭТОГО НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЕТСЯ: «Мы скучали (по ком?) - ПО ВАС».
Выражение «скучали по вам» - изменяет падеж местоимения. А это звучит хотя и «современно», но не по-русски.

Comment: "Она скучает о сыне" – п.п., добавляем букву "п" к предлогу "о", падеж от этого не изменяется (надеюсь меня слышно, даже если я не кричу заглавными буквами): "Она скучает по сыне". Убедительно и очень по-русски, да. (На всякий случай: это был сарказм.)

Comment: @LarisaSvetlichnaya Простите, но **так** много — и ни о чём.